# Tasks и локальный DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Есть такой вот метод

```
async Task<DataTable> TestAsync(string mySelectQuery, DB2Connection myConnection)
        {
            Task<DataTable> us = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command(mySelectQuery, myConnection))
                {
                    using (DbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            dt.Load(myReader);

                            return dt;
                    }
                }
            });

            return await us;
        }
```

Вызываю так:

```
IEnumerable<Task<DataTable>> tasks = from unds in new [] { "select * from test1", "select * from test2" } select TestAsync(unds, myConnection);

DataTable[] uds = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

И выдается исключение

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

Кто то может мне объяснить почему в этом случае `DataTable` дает ошибку? он же локальный, а при асинхре ведь метод копируется и все его локальные переменные тоже?
А вот если сделать вот так, то ошибки нет!

```
lock (ob)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(myReader);
     return dt; 
}
```

Comment: Асинхронный метод, который содержит только `return await` - это глупо. Из вашего кода можно убрать слова `async` и `await` без потери смысла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `DB2Connection` не предназначен для работы в двух потоках сразу. Вам надо создавать отдельное соединение на каждый запрос.

Comment: Да но так увеличивается время выполнения. А если использовать один коннект но загружать в `DataTable` в конструкции lock то так на 2сек. быстрее. Или есть вариант по лучше как делать асинхронные запросы в БД?

Comment: @Dmitriy ваша конструкция `lock` заставляет загружать данные последовательно. Того же самого эффекта вы можете добаиться, если вместо параллельного выполнения запросов сделаете их последовательно.

Comment: мне нужно делать каждый раз запросы порядка к 10 таблицам и если это делать последовательно, то это будет влиять на производительность приложения. Хотелось бы выкрутиться параллельными запросами. Это возможно? есть ли пример?

Comment: @Dmitriy да, возможно - если использовать разные соединения.